# Jenkins Jacoco SonarQube integration

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-plugins, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

I need to build a Jenkins job that takes an action like move files between folders based on code coverage values from Jacoco/SonarQube. I need some guidance on how Jenkins can get the coverage from jacoco-it.exec or SonarQube coverage values.

Thanks,
Satya

Comment: for what kind of projects do you need this? Like, iOS (Swift), Android (java)??

Comment: Its a java project, Git is the repository. I am able to generate Jacoco reports

Answer (score 2):

You need to first install "SonarQube Scanner Plugin" and setup SonarQube server configuration in Global Tool settings of jenkins.
Then In job Configuration-> Build -> SonarQube Scanner mention following properties related to jacoco along with sonar project related properties.

```
`sonar.host.url=http://xxx:9000/sonar
 sonar.projectKey=xxx
 sonar.projectName=xxx
 sonar.projectVersion=1.0.0
 sonar.sources=xxx/src/main
 sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
 sonar.language=java
 sonar.java.binaries=xxx/target/classes
 sonar.tests=xxx/src/test
 sonar.junit.reportsPath=xxx/target/surefire-reports
 sonar.surefire.reportsPath=xxx/target/surefire-reports
 sonar.jacoco.reportPath=xxx/target/jacoco-it.exec
 sonar.binaries=xxx/target/classes
 sonar.java.coveragePlugin=jacoco
 sonar.verbose=true`
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not having any idea about the Jacoco but, I can help you with Sonarqube.

First, you have to install the Sonarqube in the machine where you are running your Jenkins. It's lightweight, you can see the details here on how to instal it on your machine: https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Get+Started+in+Two+Minutes

Secondly, On jenkins You have to have the plugins and set it up with server details and all which you can find in this detailed documentaion from Sonarqube: https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Jenkins

Let me know if you need any help.